# How to solve invalid_client error in sign in with apple?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, ruby-on-rails-7, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to implement sign in with apple for my android app. I am able to login using apple id but while verifying token I am getting "invalid_client" error. I read few blogs where they were saying the problem can be with JWT token. I tried to use different method to sign JWT token but still the error is same. I am doing all these things from backend which is in RoR (Using rails 7.0.4). Following is the piece of code how I am encoding JWT token and trying to validate it on Apple server:

```
# I have .p8 file which I have downloaded from Apple developer portal for Sign in with Apple
def private_key
  key_path = "path_to_p8_key_file_path"
  OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(IO.read(key_file_path))  
end

def client_secret
  payload = {
    iss: "team_id",
    iat: Time.now.to_i,
    exp: Time.now.to_i + 3600,
    aud: "https://appleid.apple.com",
    sub: "my_reveresed_subdomain.service_id"
  }
  headers = { kid: "p8_key_id"}

  JWT.encode(payload, private_key, 'ES256', headers)
end

def validate_token
  token_url = "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token"
 
  body = {
    client_id: "my_reveresed_subdomain.service_id",
    client_secret: client_secret,
    code: "code_received_from_apple_authorize_response",
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    redirect_uri: "https_redirect_url"
  }

  response =
    Faraday.post(url) do |req|
      req.body = JSON.dump(body)
    end

  put "Response: #{response}" # here I get invalid_client error everytime
end
```

Following ways I have tried but still getting the same invalid_client error.

1. I tried to encode JWT token by converting p8 key to pem
2. Tried to change client id from service id to bundle id (App id which is reversed subdomain only)
3. Tried adding payload and headers on https://jwt.io/ website and used the encoded token

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.